# How to disable Copy but enable Paste in a WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am using a WebView to show my website on my mobile Android app. I have disabled text selection in the WebView as I want to disable Copy.

I actually wish to allow the user to Paste a text but not Copy.

How can I do that please ?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    WebView webview;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

        webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
                String domain = "www.google.fr";

                if (host.equals(domain)) {
                    // This is my website, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                    return false;
                } else {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                }
            }


        });

        webview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.fr");

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know to copy a text you need to long press it to select.

So please add a longClickListener to the webview which will show anything else on long click instead of copying the text.

```
mWebView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return true;
    }
});
mWebView.setLongClickable(false);
```

But this will also disable using PASTE so to paste content from clipboard. I will suggest add a small button beside it and add an onClickListener to it which will paste the copied content to wherever you want.

```
ClipboardManager mClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
String pasteData = "";
if (!(mClipboard.hasPrimaryClip())) {

} else if (!(mClipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN))) {
} else {
    ClipData.Item item = mClipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);

    copiedText = item.getText().toString(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this did not change anything. The text is still not selectable and copying is disabled but I am unable to paste. What could I please do to only disable Copy in the LongClick Listener ? Thank you

Comment: @JojoRaoul I may have added an extra button with paste icon and set an onClickListener to it.. I've mentioned that in my updated answer.